# How to revise Google Script App to extract multiple items and items within arrays

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, flatmap

I want to extract items from this API: https://flowhub.stoplight.io/docs/public-developer-portal/b41c3d4f8d234-orders-by-location

I'm using this script (I replaced all the keys with "CAN'T-BE-SHARED-PUBLICLY"):

```
function import_salestest() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var copysheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales");
var options = {
"method" : "GET",
"headers" : {
"clientId" : "CAN'T-BE-SHARED-PUBLICLY",
"key": "CAN'T-BE-SHARED-PUBLICLY"}}
var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.flowhub.co/v1/orders/findByLocationId/CAN'T-BE-SHARED-PUBLICLY?created_after=2023-01-14",options).getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(text);
var values = json.orders.map(({name,customerId,createdAt,orderType,_id}) => [name,customerId,createdAt,orderType,_id]);
copysheet.getRange(2, 1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

I want to revise this code:

```
var values = json.orders.map(({name,customerId,createdAt,orderType,_id}) => [name,customerId,createdAt,orderType,_id]);
```

at the moment the code extracts only the following items:

- name

  customerId

  createdAt

  orderType

  _id

I want to revise it to be able to extra the following items (in the order of the list), each item will have its own column, there are 57 items, so I want to fill up the sheet from the A column to the BE column:

- _id

  customerId

  name

  createdAt

  orderType

  customerType

  voided

  fullName

  "totals[FinalTotal]

  totals[SubTotal]

  totals[TotalDiscounts]

  totals[TotalFees]

  totals[TotalTaxes]

  payments[_id]

  payments[paymentType]

  payments[amount]

  payments[cardId]

  payments[loyaltyPoints]

  payments[debitProvider]

  payments[balanceAfterPayment]

  itemsInCart[id]

  itemsInCart[sku]

  itemsInCart[category]

  itemsInCart[title1]

  itemsInCart[title2]

  itemsInCart[productName]

  itemsInCart[strainName]

  itemsInCart[unitOfWeight]

  itemsInCart[quantity]

  itemsInCart[unitPrice]

  itemsInCart[totalPrice]

  itemsInCart[unitCost]

  itemsInCart[totalCost]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[_id]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[name]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[type]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[discountAmount]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[discountType]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[discountId]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[dollarsOff]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[penniesOff]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[percentOff]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[discounterName]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[discounterId]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[isCartDiscount]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[couponCode]]

  itemsInCart[itemDiscounts[quantity]]

  itemsInCart[tax[_id]]

  itemsInCart[tax[name]]

  itemsInCart[tax[percentage]]

  itemsInCart[tax[calculateBeforeDiscounts]]

  itemsInCart[tax[supplierSpecificTax]]

  itemsInCart[tax[excludeCustomerGroups]]

  itemsInCart[tax[enableCostMarkup]]

  itemsInCart[tax[markupPercentage]]

  itemsInCart[tax[thisTaxInPennies]]

  itemsInCart[tax[appliesTo]]"

**Here is an output of `Logger.log(text)`;**

```
Logging output too large. Truncating output. {"total":1180,"orders":[{"_id":"8m98cmknnZnctwbe17cW1t","clientId":"zGYpxLzvs2L2MFb4M","createdAt":"2023-01-14T00:12:04.184Z","customerId":"11zhl1tlwg0a","currentPoints":156,"customerType":"recCustomer","name":"X","locationId":"Y","locationName":"Z","itemsInCart":[{"category":"PackedBud","sku":"xY9qjsK6ph","title1":"Meatbreath | Joint","title2":"Calendar Islands","brand":"Calendar Islands","strainName":"Meatbreath | Joint","productName":"Meatbreath | Joint | Joints","quantity":1,"unitPrice":7.27,"totalPrice":7.27,"unitOfWeight":"Gram","unitCost":0.01,"totalCost":0.01,"itemDiscounts":[],"tax":[{"_id":"5y9mb4hGhmcXexii3","name":"MMJ","percentage":10,"appliesTo":"rec","calculateBeforeDiscounts":false,"supplierSpecificTax":false,"excludeCustomerGroups":[],"enableCostMarkup":false,"thisTaxInPennies":73}],"id":"dzFp2Gje8GvaJzShM"},{"category":"PackedBud","sku":"HBNJhyzfYu","title1":"Sneaky Pete | Joint","title2":"Brilliant Buds","brand":"Brilliant Buds","strainName":"Sneaky Pete | Joint","productName":"Sneaky Pete | Joint | Joints","quantity":1,"unitPrice":9.09,"totalPrice":9.09,"unitOfWeight":"Gram","unitCost":5,"totalCost":5,"itemDiscounts":[],"tax":[{"_id":"5y9mb4hGhmcXexii3","name":"MMJ","percentage":10,"appliesTo":"rec","calculateBeforeDiscounts":false,"supplierSpecificTax":false,"excludeCustomerGroups":[],"enableCostMarkup":false,"thisTaxInPennies":91}],"id":"zvQoFBXfeye7uaGco"},{"category":"PackedBud","sku":"xow2pDF6Rv","title1":"Cookies & Cream | Joint","title2":"Brilliant Buds","brand":"Brilliant Buds","strainName":"Cookies & Cream | Joint","productName":"Cookies & Cream | Joint | Joints","quantity":3,"unitPrice":4.55,"totalPrice":13.65,"unitOfWeight":"Gram","unitCost":3.5,"totalCost":10.5,"itemDiscounts":[],"tax":[{"_id":"5y9mb4hGhmcXexii3","name":"MMJ","percentage":10,"appliesTo":"rec","calculateBeforeDiscounts":false,"supplierSpecificTax":false,"excludeCustomerGroups":[],"enableCostMarkup":false,"thisTaxInPennies":137}],"id":"QjBMKe7tY9Rn5fDJ8"}],"voided":false,"fullName":"X","orderType":"in-store","payments":[{"_id":"bb91d108-4231-44e7-b6de-67b50242d9fe","amount":3500,"cardId":"6908","paymentType":"debit","debitProvider":"manual"},{"_id":"79d422e0-0c15-45a9-a311-9090100b961f","amount":198,"paymentType":"change"}],"totals":{"finalTotal":33.02,"subTotal":30.009999999999998,"totalDiscounts":0,"totalFees":0,"totalTaxes":3.01},"completedOn":"2023-01-14T00:12:04.184Z","orderStatus":"sold","budtender":"X"},{"_id":"dW7gxCSAX8iEiE7BrkeYUk","clientId":"zGYpxLzvs2L2MFb4M","createdAt":"2023-01-14T00:19:35.101Z","customerId":"cwm9hl58bt8xi","currentPoints":915,"customerType":"recCustomer","name":"X","locationId":"Y","locationName":"Z","itemsInCart":[{"category":"Edible","sku":"QFw4YLbc94","title1":"Glaze - Gummy - Twin Pack Grape / Strawberry","title2":"Glaze","brand":"Glaze","productName":"Glaze - Gummy - Twin Pack Grape / Strawberry","quantity":1,"unitPrice":20.46,"totalPrice":20.46,"unitOfWeight":"Each","unitCost":10,"totalCost":10,"itemDiscounts":[{"_id":"c861f5cf-a778-41df-bbe8-6e3f364add23","discounterId":"n37owKPqBkwkZWaEP","discounterName":"Clayton Brooks","discountType":"inline","name":"wonka","type":"percent","isCartDiscount":true,"percentOff":"10","discountAmount":227}],"tax":[{"_id":"5y9mb4hGhmcXexii3","name":"MMJ","percentage":10,"appliesTo":"rec","calculateBeforeDiscounts":false,"supplierSpecificTax":false,"excludeCustomerGroups":[],"enableCostMarkup":false,"thisTaxInPennies":205}],"id":"zWwPbpFJHDoqk3iSF"},{"category":"Edible","sku":"2iAAi6FqzQ","title1":"Glaze - Gummy - Berry Berry Party","title2":"Glaze","brand":"Glaze","productName":"Glaze - Gummy - Berry Berry Party","quantity":2,"unitPrice":20.46,"totalPrice":40.92,"unitOfWeight":"Each","unitCost":10,"totalCost":20,"itemDiscounts":[{"_id":"c861f5cf-a778-41df-bbe8-6e3f364add23","discounterId":"n37owKPqBkwkZWaEP","discounterName":"Clayton Brooks","discountType":"inline","name":"wonka","type":"percent","isCartDiscount":true,"percentOff":"10","discountAmount":454}],"tax":[{"_id":"5y9mb4hGhmcXexii3","name":"MMJ","percentage":10,"appliesTo":"rec","calculateBeforeDiscounts":false,"supplierSpecificTax":false,"excludeCustomerGroups":[],"enableCostMarkup":false,"thisTaxInPennies":409}],"id":"QXCqSSbqkqp5QZ5sG"}],"voided":false,"fullName":"","orderType":"in-store","payments":[{"_id":"6772048f-8607-451f-92b8-1c0b5de4ad94","amount":8000,"paymentType":"cash"},{"_id":"4150820e-e170-4c15-b13d-0228e0d61409","amount":1248,"paymentType":"change"}],"totals":{"finalTotal":67.52,"subTotal":61.38,"totalDiscounts":6.81,"totalFees":0,"totalTaxes":6.14},"completedOn":"2023-01-14T00:19:35.101Z","orderStatus":"sold","budtender":"X"},{"_id":"j7XtXDBxFbbqZ3JCdh1sF1","clientId":"zGYpxLzvs2L2MFb4M","createdAt":"2023-01-14T00:21:42.916Z","customerId":"8uzkbil08o3sg2","currentPoints":74,"customerType":"recCustomer","name":"X","locationId":"Y","locationName":"Z","itemsInCart":[{"category":"PackedBud","sku":"wLyQyXYGT3","title1":"Say Less | Flower","title2":"Kings Stache","brand":"Kings Stache","strainName":"Say Less | Flower","productName":"Say Less | Flower | Eighths","quantity":1,"unitPrice":31.82,"totalPrice":31.82,"unitOfWeight":"Eighth","unitCost":15.62,"totalCost":15.62,"itemDiscounts":[],"tax":[{"_id":"5y9mb4hGhmcXexii3","name":"MMJ","percentage":10,"appliesTo":"rec","calculateBeforeDiscounts":false,"supplierSpecificTax":false,"excludeCustomerGroups":[],"enableCostMarkup":false,"thisTaxInPennies":318}],"id":"navmgGLGKdusQCaaG"},{"category":"PackedBud","sku":"twsRYMsBLR","title1":"Musty Buffalo | Flower","title2":"Kings Stache","brand":"Kings Stache","strainName":"Musty Buffalo | Flower","productName":"Musty Buffalo | Flower | Eighths","quantity":1,"unitPrice":31.82,"totalPrice":31.82,"unitOfWeight":"Eighth","unitCost":15.62,"totalCost":15.62,"itemDiscounts":[],"tax":[{"_id":"5y9mb4hGhmcXexii3","name":"MMJ","percentage":10,"appliesTo":"rec","calculateBeforeDiscounts":false,"supplierSpecificTax":false,"excludeCustomerGroups":[],"enableCostMarkup":false,"thisTaxInPennies":318}],"id":"5gff84yTuP7nawjQ9"}],"voided":false,"fullName":"X","orderType":"in-store","payments":[{"_id":"88d570d5-3e1d-4bfb-85d7-7732e49dcc8f","amount":7000,"paymentType":"cash"},{"_id":"fc55747c-70d3-4b88-8f21-d4b86cd7a5b1","amount":0,"paymentType":"change"}],"totals":{"finalTotal":70,"subTotal":63.64,"totalDiscounts":0,"totalFees":0,"totalTaxes":6.36},"completedOn":"2023-01-14T00:21:42.916Z","orderStatus":"sold","budtender":"X"},{"_id":"fG1ELYzAFWWwtm9qKDD7zd","clientId":"zGYpxLzvs2L2MFb4M","createdAt":"2023-01-14T00:34:32.772Z","customerId":"125vuk77hl397ad32","currentPoints":600,"customerType":"recCustomer","name":"Corey Bauman","locationId":"Y","locationName":"Z","itemsInCart":[{"category":"PackedBud","sku":"xow2pDF6Rv","title1":"Cookies & Cream | Joint","title2":"Brilliant Buds","brand":"Brilliant Buds","strainName":"Cookies & Cream | Joint","productName":"Cookies & Cream | Joint | Joints","quantity":2,"unitPrice":4.55,"totalPrice":9.1,"unitOfWeight":"Gram","unitCost":3.5,"totalCost":7,"itemDiscounts":[],"tax":[{"_id":"5y9mb4hGhmcXexii3","name":"MMJ","percentage":10,"appliesTo":"rec","calculateBeforeDiscounts":false,"supplierSpecificTax":false,"excludeCustomerGroups":[],"enableCostMarkup":false,"thisTaxInPennies":91}],"id":"QjBMKe7tY9Rn5fDJ8"}],"voided":false,"fullName":"X","orderType":"in-store","payments":[{"_id":"fae9ed06-e410-4ae3-8730-085da485e737","amount":1001,"paymentType":"cash"},{"_id":"6a1a5e4d-a134-4599-917f-9e2d6f614a92","amount":0,"paymentType":"change"}],"totals":{"finalTotal":10.01,"subTotal":9.1,"totalDiscounts":0,"totalFees":0,"totalTaxes":0.91},"completedOn":"2023-01-14T00:34:32.772Z","orderStatus":"sold","budtender":"X"},{"_id":"gxB3U378AgrGXY2HAyuay3","clientId":"zGYpxLzvs2L2MFb4M","createdAt":"2023-01-14T00:35:38.653Z","customerId":"ebufzil0b8n2p8","currentPoints":251,"customerType":"recCustomer","name":"X
```

Comment: I can really use your help on this @Tanaike 

Comment: Can you provide the sample values of `text`? Because, I cannot know your values. By this, I cannot think of the solution. I apologize for this.

Comment: Sure! can you please tell me if it's enough @Tanaike?
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1enG9HQn6tjQsw3Hnn8KtE078KJ0HJhecE0VLFsH6cPk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample value. But, unfortunately, your provided value is from `Logger.log(json)`. In this case, unfortunately, this value is not JSON data. In this case, this value cannot be used. So, I asked about the value of `text`. I apologize for this. I apologize for this.

Comment: Please include all relevant details in the question rather than linking to external files. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: very sorry about that! my mistake! can you please tell me how I can share the value of "text" with you? what do I need to do? @Tanaike

Comment: How would you go about sharing sensitive data? if it is included in the question it won't be possible to remove it right? @doubleunary

Comment: I'm not sure about your sample value of `text`, can you add it to your question?

Comment: Sure, would you like me to add to my questions the `Logger.log(text);` output? @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. About `would you like me to add to my questions the Logger.log(text); output?`, I had asked about this from my 1st comment.

Comment: I'm very sorry, it's my fault, your English is perfect! I updated the questions, I removed sensitive data, please let me know if you need anything else @@Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your added sample data, `orderId` is not found. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your sample data or your expected value. I apologize for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251358/discussion-between-kal-el-and-tanaike).